# SQL 2008. How to amend partition schema to make new partitions to lay in new filegroup?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, partitioning

I am going to partition my tables by 1 day of data in each.

For backup/archiving purposes I might need to store few months of data in different file groups.

My plan is something like: all partitions (1 day each) for 2010 in one file then 2011 in another.

*But by the end of 2011 I will need to create new data file and new filegroup and I want the 2012 partitions to be placed in that new filegroup.*

**How do I force new partitions to go into new filegroup?**

Comment: You are aware that you have a 1000 partition limit, so 3 years of data partitioned per day will break.

Comment: the 1000 partitions is the for SQL 2005 & SQL Server 2008 RTM, in SQL Server 2008 SP1 the limit is 15000. But ideally at some point in the past partitions are to be merged in one `history` partition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In terms of how you create a new partition into a new filegroup, before splitting the partition function you use the ALTER PARTITION SCHEMA syntax:

```
ALTER PARTITION SCHEME YourPartitionSchemeName
NEXT USED yourChosenFileGroup
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190347.aspx

Comment: so I just alter the scheme adding new FG and you believe is nothing will be broken with already created partitions? no side-effects? (that what my worry was)...

Comment: Create new filegroup, set next used, split the partition function. That's it.